# Find max number of consecutive days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The code below groups the dataframe by a key.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'date', 'cnt'])
 df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date']) 
 for c_id, group in df.groupby('id'):
        print(c_id)
        print(group)
```

This produces a result like this:

```
    id       date  cnt
    1 2019-01-02    1
   1 2019-01-03    2
   1 2019-01-04    3
   1 2019-01-05    1
   1 2019-01-06    2
   1 2019-01-07    1

    id       date      cnt
    2 2019-01-01   478964
    2 2019-01-02   749249
   2 2019-01-03  1144842
   2 2019-01-04  1540846
   2 2019-01-05  1444918
   2 2019-01-06  1624770
   2 2019-01-07  2227589

    id       date     cnt
    3 2019-01-01   41776
   3 2019-01-02   82322
   3 2019-01-03   93467
   3 2019-01-04   56674
   3 2019-01-05   47606
   3 2019-01-06   41448
   3 2019-01-07  145827


    id       date     cnt
    4 2019-01-01   41776
   4 2019-01-02   82322
   4 2019-01-06   93467
   4 2019-01-07   56674
```

From this result, I want to find the maximum consecutive number of days for each id. So id 1 would be 6, id 2 would be 7, id 3 would be 7, and id 4 would be 2.

Comment: There a duplicate index `1` in group 3 and 4. Is that intentional?

Comment: Nah, that is not intentional. That was from the result set. It has nothing to do with actual data.

Comment: @QuangHoang i just took it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
m = (df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])) #if necessary convert else drop
       .groupby('id')['date']
       .diff()
       .gt(pd.Timedelta('1D'))
       .cumsum())
df.groupby(['id', m]).size().max(level='id')
```

**Output**

```
id
1    6
2    7
3    7
4    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your result, run:

```
result = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda grp: grp.groupby(
    (grp.date.shift() + pd.Timedelta(1, 'd') != grp.date).cumsum())
    .id.count().max())
```

Details:

- `df.groupby('id')` - First level grouping (by *id*).
- `grp.groupby(...)` - Second level grouping (by sequences
  of consecutive dates.
- `grp.date.shift()` - Date from the previous row.
- `+ pd.Timedelta(1, 'd')` - Shifted by 1 day.
- `!= grp.date` - Not equal to the current date. The result
  is a *Series* with *True* on the start of each sequence of
  consecutive dates.
- `cumsum()` - Convert the above (*bool*) *Series* to a *Series*
  of *int* - consecutive numbers of above sequences, starting
  from 1.
- `id` - Take *id* column from each (second level) group.
- `count()` - Compute the size of the current group.
- `.max()` - Take *max* from sizes of second level groups
  (within the current level 1 group).

Comment: Yes. This is the second level grouping (by sequences of consecutive dates).

Comment: I think It could be too slow